# How can I merge different columns using pandas without NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge different columns and I used code as follows:

```
r1= len(data['Answer_h1_Happy'])
c1 = len(list(data))

ndata1 = list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) + list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) + 
    list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) + list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) \
    + list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) + list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) + 
    list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) + list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) \
    + list(data.Answer_h1_Happy) + list(data.Answer_h1_Happy)
r1 = len(ndata1) - r1
t1 = r1 * c1
dfnan1 = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape([np.nan]*t1, (r1,c1)), columns=list(data))
data= data.append(dfnan1)
data['Happy'] = ndata1
```

When I try to merge only this, it works well. But when I try to merge other columns, because of 'NaN' the column get thousands of rows.

For example, the original table looks like this:
[original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFUKx.png)

And after 1st merge, NaNs are created in black rows.
[after 1st merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niSKC.png)

When I try to merge other column, it gets twice longer than other.
[after 2nd merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIpjA.png)

Is there any way I can merge without Nan? [This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPRMu.png)

Comment: Did you try ```pd.get_dummies(your_data)``` see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html for more information.

Comment: @ItamarCohen but I want everything in the same column. One for URL, one for happy, one for sad...etc.

Comment: Can you share these as text, rather than image links? Something like the output of `df.head()` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I move combined columns to another data frame.
After that code I add,

```
df['Input_image_url'] = data.pop('Input_image_url').reset_index(drop=True)
```

and remove all NaN by,

```
update_data = data.drop(df.index[13:130])
```

And it works!!